# Get current page/ view name in RC0 returns “t”

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I wish to handle the hardware back button for that i need to get the name of the current view.

```
console.log(this.nav.getActive());
 console.log(this.navCtrl.getActive().component.name);
```

This just returns the letter t on the device but does work in the browser.

Kindly let me know as to how can I get the page/view name on the device for handling back button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that webpack is minifying the code when running the app on the device (with the --prod flag I guess) and that's why the name is correct when working on the browser, but shows `t` as the name when running the app on the device. **In order to avoid this, you can use the `instanceof` operator to check if a page is the page you're looking for to do something.**

This is how I handle the back button in one of the apps I've worked on:

```
this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
    this.handleBackButton();
});
```

And then

```
private handleBackButton(): void {

    // Prevent to dismiss a modal when another modal is being dismissed
    let ready = true;

    let activePortal = this.ionicApp._loadingPortal.getActive() ||
        this.ionicApp._modalPortal.getActive() ||
        this.ionicApp._toastPortal.getActive() ||
        this.ionicApp._overlayPortal.getActive();

    if (activePortal) {
        ready = false;
        activePortal.dismiss();
        activePortal.onDidDismiss(() => { ready = true; });
        return;
    }

    if (this.menuCtrl.isOpen()) {
        this.menuCtrl.close();
        return;
    }

    let view = this.navCtrl.getActive();
    let page = view ? this.navCtrl.getActive().instance : null;

    if (page && (page instanceof HomePage || page instanceof SignInPage)) {
        this.platform.exitApp();
    }
    else if (this.navCtrl.canGoBack() || view && view.isOverlay) {
        this.navCtrl.pop();
    } else {
        this.accountService.isLoggedIn() ? this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage) : this.navCtrl.setRoot(SignInPage);
    }
}
```

As you can see in the code, I check if the view is a particular view by using the `instanceof` operator

```
page instanceof HomePage
```

**That way it should work even when webpacks minifies the code.**

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.

Comment: Np, glad to help :)